# How to protect a WHERE...IN SQL statement from Injection

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, sql-injection

I'm wondering about the feasibility of protecting a SQL statement similar to the following, using Entity Framework's `DbContext.ExecuteSqlCommand`:

`DELETE FROM HugeDataTable WHERE Id IN (1, 4, 6, 74, 82)`

Basically, I have a scenario where my table has a binary column of arbitrary length and I need to delete the row.  Since we're using Entity Framework, I would normally do something like this:

```
// Data Structure
Parent: some object
Item: has a foreign key to Parent (ParentId)
Contents: has a foreign key to Item (ItemId)

// This is a little contrived, but it's meant to illustrate the point.
var parentId = 2;
var childItems = _context
     .Items
     .Include(item => item.Contents)
     .Select(item => item.ParentId == parentid)
     .ToList();

if (childItems.Any())
{
   // I'm using DbContext, not IDbContext, so I have access to RemoveRange()
   var contents = childItems.Select(item => item.Contents).ToList();
   _context.ItemContents.RemoveRange(contents);
   _context.Items.RemoveRange(childItems);
}
```

The problem here is that `Contents` could be huge -- megabytes or larger.  So I am pulling all that data into memory via Entity Framework in the first query, then copying it in memory when I do the `Select` later.  The easy solution here would be to drop the `Include` and do a straight SQL query to delete the Contents -- after all, I don't actually *need* that binary data in order to delete the row; I just need the foreign key value of the row.

Here's where we get to my dilemma.

At this point, I have a few options.  The one I ended up going with was this:

```
var childItems = _context
     .Items
     .Select(item => item.ParentId == parentId)
     .ToList();

if (childItems.Any())
{
   foreach (var child in childItems)
   {
      var sql = "DELETE FROM Content WHERE ItemId = @itemId";
      _context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(
           sql,
           new SqlParameter("@itemId", child.Id));
   }
}
```

That works, but I'm wondering if I could do better.  I could ditch the `foreach` and just do this:

```
if (childItems.Any())
{
   var sql = "DELETE FROM Content WHERE ItemId IN (@itemIds)";
   var itemIds = childItems.Select(item => item.Id.ToString()).ToArray();
   _context.DataBase.ExecuteSqlCommand(
        sql,
        new SqlParameter("@itemIds", string.Join(",", itemIds));
}
```

Boom.  One query, no `foreach` loop.  But I'm wondering about the safety of that, or if I've just blown away the entire usefulness of parameterizing the query in the first place.

Also, I'm thinking this may end up being a micro-optimization.  Yeah, more queries are slower than fewer queries, but I'm looking at a service that does this that's on the same physical network as the database, and the big optimization is not pulling all the contents into memory twice via doing this with straight Entity Framework classes.

So my ultimate question is: is it possible to parameterize a `WHERE...IN` query like this?  Or does that defeat the purpose of parameterizing it in the first place?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Two reasons: 1.) I don't think we have cascade deletes set up on our DB (I don't know why; it's an architectural decision that predates my arrival), and 2.) without cascade deletes set up, I'm not sure if `RemoveRange` will actually delete everything in the hierarchy.

Comment: @AriRoth It can delete everything if cascade delete is set up on the `DbContext` configuration, regardless of what the database states

Comment: @cowbert I see why one could think that, but I'd argue that it's not (and not just because I wrote it :) ).  I'm asking about a specific case here -- `WHERE...IN` queries, not a general "how to parameterize a query" type of thing.

Comment: @cowbert Yep, ok.  I didn't catch that somehow.  No arguments here. :)